# Do we need certificate to add WCF service reference in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am getting following error while adding WCF service reference.

There was an error downloading 'https://test.aaa.com/AAAService/AAAService.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://test.aaa.com/AAAService/AAAService.svc'.
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Is this because i do not have certificate in my local computer?

Comment: This is happening because the site is responding with a 403 error. In order to know why the site is doing that, you have to know something about the site. If they are using the status code correctly, it means you failed to authenticate... which might mean many things. It depends on the specific web site.

Comment: It's more likely that the remote service requires you to authenticate to prove you are authorized, but you didn't supply any valid credential. You could try adding service reference as http(s)://user:pass@someservice.com/some.svc?WSDL but really it depends how auth is configured - maybe you can open it in VS web browser and log in then you'll have an auth cookie.. not enough info to answer really